# Can't get a select statement to work within subprogram

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a subprogram that will take an input zipcode and then prompt the user to enter in a new zipcode which will then update the database.  If the zipcode that is not in the database it will a display a message.  Something isn't working with the select statement

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT p_find_zip PROMPT 'Please enter a 5 digit zip code:'

DECLARE
  find_zip char(5) :=&p_find_zip;
  v_zip  char(5);
BEGIN
  SELECT zip
    INTO v_zip
  FROM zipcodes
  WHERE find_zip = v_zip;

  if find_zip = v_zip then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the select is working');
  end if;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THAT ZIP IS NOT IN THE DATABASE');
END;
/
```

If the zipcode matches what's in the database then, it should print 'the select is working'

if the zipcode does not match it should print 'that zip is not in the database'

table data:

```
67226   Wichita
60606   Fort Dodge
50302   Kansas City
54444   Columbia
66002   Liberal
61111   Fort Hays
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your zip column in the zipcodes table is called **zip** your query should be like below:

```
SELECT zip
INTO v_zip
FROM zipcodes
WHERE zip = find_zip;
```

The condition **find_zip = v_zip** will give u nothing back.

Also condition **if find_zip = v_zip then** is redundant as your NO_DATA_FOUND will be raised anyway so you will always print 'the select is working' when data is found only.

Comment: This gave me back an error that ZIP must be declared.  Zip is the column name for the zipcodes table

Comment: Where zip = find_zip works resolved issue.  If statement issue you were concerned with doesn't occur.  thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Well if it helped I would expect you accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
create table NS_zipcodes3(zipcode varchar(5),city varchar(20));

insert into NS_zipcodes3 values('67226','Wichita');
insert into NS_zipcodes3 values('60606' ,  'Fort Dodge');
insert into NS_zipcodes3 values('50302'  , 'Kansas City');
insert into NS_zipcodes3 values('54444' ,  'Columbia');
insert into NS_zipcodes3 values('66002',  'Liberal');
insert into NS_zipcodes3 values('61111' ,  'Fort Hays');
select * from NS_zipcodes3;


SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

 DECLARE
  find_zip varchar(10);
  v_zip  varchar(5);
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('please enter a 5 digit zipcode') ;
    select :p_find_zip into find_zip from dual;
  SELECT zipcode
    INTO v_zip
  FROM NS_zipcodes
  WHERE zipcode = find_zip;

  if to_number(find_zip) =to_number(v_zip) then
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('the select is working');
  end if;

EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THAT ZIP IS NOT IN THE DATABASE');
WHEN others THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('invalid zipcode entered');

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether zip code existing in your table you can do some thing like below:

select count(1) into v_zip from zipcodes where maintenance_seq_no=find_zip;

if v_zip <>0 then

dbms_output.put_line('Zip Code exists');

else

dbms_output.put_line('Zip Code does not exists');

end if;